# XML Parsing in Android: Getting Exception

Tags: android, xml, parsing, url, using

For this given code I am getting an exception.  I don't know how to clear this.

```
package com.new_xml_parse;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class New_xml_parseActivity extends Activity 
{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
/** Create a new layout to display the view */
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(1);
/** Create a new textview array to display the results */
TextView name[];
TextView website[];
TextView category[];
try
{
URL url = new URL("http://bestpropertyworld.com/MobileApp/xml1.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
/** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */
name = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
website = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
category = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++)
{
Node node = nodeList.item(i);
name[i] = new TextView(this);
website[i] = new TextView(this);
category[i] = new TextView(this);
Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("name");
Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();
name[i].setText("Name = "+ ((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());
NodeList websiteList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("website");
Element websiteElement = (Element) websiteList.item(0);
websiteList = websiteElement.getChildNodes();
website[i].setText("Website = "+ ((Node) websiteList.item(0)).getNodeValue());
category[i].setText("Website Category = "+ websiteElement.getAttribute("category"));
layout.addView(name[i]);
layout.addView(website[i]);
layout.addView(category[i]);
}
} 
catch (Exception e)
{
System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
}
/** Set the layout view to display */
setContentView(layout);
}
}
```

in LogCat i am getting like this, Give give solution for this

```
05-18 15:16:00.132: W/WindowManager(77): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21010
05-18 15:16:00.151: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(77): setKernelCountSet(10013, 1) failed with errno -2
05-18 15:16:00.681: I/Process(77): Sending signal. PID: 187 SIG: 3
05-18 15:16:00.698: I/dalvikvm(187): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-18 15:16:01.151: I/dalvikvm(187): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-18 15:16:02.121: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(77): setKernelCountSet(10041, 0) failed with errno -2
05-18 15:16:02.902: D/dalvikvm(187): GREF has increased to 201
05-18 15:16:03.573: D/dalvikvm(187): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 594K, 6% free 11501K/12167K, paused 114ms
05-18 15:16:03.601: I/dalvikvm-heap(187): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.399MB for 1157776-byte allocation
05-18 15:16:03.851: D/dalvikvm(187): GC_CONCURRENT freed 23K, 6% free 12608K/13319K, paused 25ms+7ms
05-18 15:16:04.087: D/dalvikvm(187): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 6% free 12608K/13319K, paused 67ms
05-18 15:16:04.101: I/dalvikvm-heap(187): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.524MB for 1203064-byte allocation
05-18 15:16:04.251: D/dalvikvm(187): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 6% free 13783K/14535K, paused 18ms+7ms
05-18 15:16:04.491: D/dalvikvm(187): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 6% free 13780K/14535K, paused 49ms
05-18 15:16:04.501: I/dalvikvm-heap(187): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.625MB for 1157776-byte allocation
05-18 15:16:04.561: D/dalvikvm(187): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 5% free 14911K/15687K, paused 58ms
05-18 15:16:05.971: D/dalvikvm(187): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 56K, 4% free 16198K/16839K, paused 57ms
05-18 15:16:06.411: D/dalvikvm(187): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 16K, 4% free 17678K/18311K, paused 79ms
05-18 15:16:07.231: D/dalvikvm(187): GC_CONCURRENT freed 614K, 4% free 19055K/19847K, paused 6ms+8ms
05-18 15:16:07.391: I/ActivityManager(77): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.new_xml_parse/.New_xml_parseActivity} from pid 187
05-18 15:16:07.391: W/WindowManager(77): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21005
05-18 15:16:07.474: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(77): setKernelCountSet(10041, 1) failed with errno -2
05-18 15:16:07.637: I/System.out(572): XML Pasing Excpetion = android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-18 15:16:08.023: I/Process(77): Sending signal. PID: 572 SIG: 3
05-18 15:16:08.031: I/dalvikvm(572): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-18 15:16:08.372: I/dalvikvm(572): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-18 15:16:08.591: I/Process(77): Sending signal. PID: 572 SIG: 3
05-18 15:16:08.591: I/dalvikvm(572): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-18 15:16:08.611: I/dalvikvm(572): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-18 15:16:08.735: I/ActivityManager(77): Displayed com.new_xml_parse/.New_xml_parseActivity: +1s260ms
05-18 15:16:09.191: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(77): setKernelCountSet(10013, 0) failed with errno -2
05-18 15:16:09.224: W/InputManagerService(77): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41558698 (uid=10013 pid=187)
05-18 15:16:09.621: D/dalvikvm(187): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2277K, 12% free 18638K/21127K, paused 79ms
05-18 15:16:34.761: D/dalvikvm(172): GC_CONCURRENT freed 387K, 6% free 9534K/10119K, paused 7ms+4ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your main thread cant handle XML parsing.so use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).to complete your xml parsing.

[See this Example](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-customized-listview.html)

Comment: thaks yar..  but i dont knw where to use async task, since i m neew to android.. not able to get u clearly.. tel clearly .. wat can i do now..

Comment: It is too lenthy code.. can i have simple code for the same plz.. its very difficult for me to understand .. thanks once again..

Comment: check in `NewsMainActivity.java`  and `Newsparser.java`

Comment: is that two is enough to fetch the data from XML file which was in URL website

Comment: ya and you get data in dynamic array

Comment: I am not able to use those coding , gettting error .. can you plz suggest  some other sample program

Answer (score 0):

Your error is `NetworkOnMainThreadException` which means that you are fetching and parsing XML on the main thread (UI thread) which makes it unresponsive. See [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) to understand how you can use an `AsyncTask` to perform a long duration task in the background and populate your UI on completion.

Comment: wat i do in UI.. since i am new to android .. i m not able to get u clearly ..    can u plz tel in detail.. from this 1 thing i got is .. i have to use  AsyncTask.. but i dont know how and where.. should i create a new class?? help me in this plz.. thanks for the earlier one..

Answer (score 0):

It reports that you should background your networking functions, because it is not a good idea to block UI Thread in Android for these kind of tasks.

```
new FetchXMLAsyncTask.execute();

private class FetchXMLAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
          } 
          @Override
          protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
               // put your code here where you should fetch xml, parse it and call update ui components.
               return null;
          }

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {

         }   
      }
  }
```

Comment: I am not able to get this, clearly .. can u plz tel in detail.. from this 1 thing i got is .. i have to use  AsyncTask.. but i dont know how and where.. should i create a new class?? help me in this plz.. thanks for the earlier one..

Comment: how to do tat.. can i create inner class r wat i do ..in doInBackground method I dont knw which code I have to put..

Answer (score 0):

It Seems that the Error you are getting is due to the SERVER activity being executed on the main() thread to avoid this you have to use the AsyncTask as shown below.

paste this line of code  below in your oncreate() or onclicklistener or wherever you had placed the XMLPARSING CODE.

```
new DoXMLParsing().execute();
```

below given DoXMLParsing is a inner class which extends AsyncTask to perform background operations and publish results on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers.
Just copy and paste the class below in your activity class from which you are supposed to do the XMLPARSING.

```
public class DoXMLParsing extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


 protected void onPreExecute() {   
    //any task if you would like to perform before exe the XMLPARSING place the code here
   }


   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

       //cut and paste your whole XMLPARSING code here..

       return null;
      }

 protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

     // Here if you wish to do future process for ex. move to another activity do here

     }
 }
```

Hope This Helps..!! :)